# git-bash generate default .bashrc

Tags: windows, git-bash

Usually, there are `.bashrc, .bash_profile, .inputrc` etc. files on linux systems and they are not empty by default. They are also present when you install cygwin on Windows and, also, non-empty.

But git-bash installer doesn't create them by default.

Is it possible to trigger generation of the default `.bashrc, .bash_profile, .inputrc` in git-bash environment?

I know that generation for `.bash_profile` is triggered if you manually create empty `.bashrc`, but is it possible to trigger generation for both of them simultaneously, so both of them turn out to not be empty? And what about the default `.inputrc`?

Answer (score 1):

In the installation folder for the git system there is miniature UNIX tree including a `/etc/` folder in which the default configuration files are located.

I found the default `.bashrc` on my installation as

```
C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Programs\Git\etc\bash.bashrc
```

and I believe this is the default location, or at least close to, for that. I also saw `profile` and `inputrc` in there. So copy those to your home directory and then start modifying!